# How can I enter BIOS setup on a Commodore PC 30-III?

Tags: commodore, bios

I have a Commodore PC 30-III but I can't find a way to start the BIOS menu. It displays the following message during startup:

[image: Screenshot of Commodore 286 BIOS Rev 2.01 (ROM chip numbers 390339 - 03, 390340 - 03) having booted into MS-DOS]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> before you get the ‘Starting MS-DOS…’ prompt, but after the memory test (if any).

Comment: For reference: https://oldcrap.org/2018/10/17/commodore-pc30-iii/#jp-carousel-2599